# How to pass alpha (transparency) into seaborn.jointplot?

Tags: parameters, seaborn, alpha

I am practicing data exploration with seaborn, and recently encountered a problem: how to pass *alpha* (transparency) into `seaborn.jointplot` (onto the scatter plot part, not the histogram)?

More broadly, I would also like to know:

1. What are the general functions of `joint_kws`, `marginal_kws` and `annot_kws` (i.e. how do I use/pass pyplot parameters into these parameters?)?
2. What is the difference between these parameters and the `kwargs` parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't simply adding `alpha=0.5` to `jointplot` work?

Comment: `joint_kws = dict(alpha=0.5)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just adding `alpha=0.5` to your `sns.jointplot` call may give the following error:

```
TypeError: regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alpha'
```

So in this case, you would nest this `alpha` setting into the `scatter_kws`, then into `joint_kws`, like so:

```
sns.jointplot(x, y, data, kind='reg',joint_kws = {'scatter_kws':dict(alpha=0.5)})
```

At which point, you will get adjustment of transparancy for the scatter in the jointplot.

Comment: This method did not work using seaborn 0.11.2. Only @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's method worked for me, `joint_kws = dict(alpha=0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can simply add `alpha=0.5` into your `jointplot` call.

As for your other questions, general information can be found in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html):

1. You pass a dictionary to each of the `kw` parameters. These control the different portions of the plot created by `jointplot`. For instance, if you wanted to change the transparency of the histogram, you would pass it to `marginal_kws`. (This is a little bit more involved though since the "marginal" is created using `sns.distplot` which builds off `plt.hist`. So you would actually have `marginal_kws={'hist_kws': {'alpha': 0.1}}` for `jointplot`.
2. Additional `kwargs` affect the scatter plot portion, just like `joint_kws` will. These arguments, however, will supersede those provided by `joint_kws`.